# Cannot create "/usr/local/bin/create-create" due to insufficient permissions yarn. How to solve the problem?

Tags: error-handling, next.js, yarnpkg

Do the `yarn create next-app` and it gives the next error "Cannot create "/usr/local/bin/create-create" due to insufficient permissions yarn" - How to solve it, so yarn will install the next-app?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a command I found on [dev.to](https://dev.to/agiksetiawan/fixed-yarn-error-insufficient-permissions-13hc) that worked for me.

```
yarn config set prefix ~/.local
```